# Python - Odoo 10 | How to reset a variable based on date

Tags: python, reset, odoo-10

I'm currently using Odoo 10 and i have a little problem.

I would like an automated reset system for my module, i use one float to store an amount for my partners in odoo and i want to reset this float each month end.

I'm new in Odoo, i have no idea how to code this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I am raising a flag about this question because is too abroad for being response. You should provide some code for proving how far did you try at least, at the time, you will provide a context to other members which let them understand you and understand the specific problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways one of them is : 
    make data for cron job like

```
 <data noupdate="1">
    <!-- automatic delete my float at end of month>

    <record forcecreate="True" id="ir_cron_my_float" model="ir.cron">
        <field name="name">My Float Manger</field>
        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
        <field name="interval_number">1</field>
        <field name="interval_type">month</field>
        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
        <field eval="'your.object'" name="model"/>
        <field eval="'your_method'" name="function"/>
        <field eval="'()'" name="args"/>
    </record>
</data>

def your_method(self):
......
    your logic for reset float value like query to
    update fields to 0
......

TRY AND TEST

Thanks
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i try this now